# How to save plots one at a time from momentuHMM fit object?

Tags: r, plot, save

I'm fitting different models with the R package momentuHMM. Once fitted, the HMM model can be visualized using the plot function (i.e. plot(fitHMM.object)) which produces a graph of the 1) step length distribution, 2) turning angle distribution, 3) graphs of the transition probabilities across different covariate combinations and 4) state-colored tracks. I can either have them plot one at a time and hit "enter" after each plot to get the next plot to appear or I can use the ask = FALSE argument and it will return all plots at once.

I want to save the plots and specify the name of the files but I don't want to manually have to save each one by clicking the save button in the plotting window nor do I want them all in one pdf - I want each plot to be its own separate png(). How do I specify which graph I want plotted (i.e. just the step length distribution) so I can save it using png() and dev.off()? I tried plot(fitHMM.object, ask = FALSE, plotTracks = FALSE, which = c(1,1)) like you would for plotting a regular lm object but no luck.

Thanks.

```
library(momentuHMM)

nbStates <- 2
stepDist <- "gamma"
angleDist <- "vm"

# Example data
data <- example$m$data

mu0 <- c(20,70)
sigma0 <- c(10,30)
kappa0 <- c(1,1)
stepPar <- c(mu0, sigma0) 
anglePar <- kappa0 
formula <- ~cov1+cos(cov2)

m <- fitHMM(data=data,
           nbStates=nbStates,
           dist=list(step=stepDist, angle=angleDist),
           Par0=list(step=stepPar,angle=anglePar),
           formula=formula)

print(m)

plot(m, breaks = 25, plotTracks = FALSE)

plot(m, breaks = 25, ask = FALSE, plotTracks = FALSE)
```

Comment: You can examine the source code of the plotting function via `momentuHMM:::plot.momentuHMM`, or [here](https://github.com/bmcclintock/momentuHMM/blob/master/R/plot_momentuHMM.R). Unfortunately it looks like this is one giant monolithic function.  You might end up having to contact the maintainer or asking on the [issues list](https://github.com/bmcclintock/momentuHMM/issues) ...

Comment: It [looks like](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/momentuHMM/index.html) the `momentuHMM` package uses `ggplot2` for creating graphics, so I think you should be able to start with a simple `for` loop, make a plot, call `ggsave(.)`, and move on. Keep in mind that ggplot within `for` loops can behave not like you would expect, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/2547306/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/4811106/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/15678261/3358272.

Comment: @r2evans, unfortunately I think the `plot.momentuHMM` method does **not** use `ggplot2` (see the link above) ...

Comment: I updated the question to have an example from the package. It definitely looks like base plot to me and ggsave does not work but regardless either one plot is plotted at a time asking me to enter "return" after each plot or all are returned at once.

Comment: @BenBolker okay, my thought was premature, stemming from the fact that the package suggests `ggplot2` but not `graphics` or such.

Comment: Honestly, I can't think of a way to do what the OP wants without hacking the function (not impossible, but tedious).

Comment: If I had to do this I would create the PDF and then [split the PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49329695/split-pdf-according-to-pages-in-r) and convert to PNG as necessary ...